# Facing issue in configuring domain name to Django webserver

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have created the Django web app and deployed to ec2 instance using Nginx and supervisor it is working fine.

I bout new domain and I configured its AWS route 53. I am able to see my domain name is mapping for aws instance.

But when I try to access the Django web app it's giving 404.

I have updated the server_name parm in my Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name equitynotify.com;

  location {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/**/***/***/source/prod/boo-gateway/boogateway/app.sock;
    }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /******/path;
}
```

Even I added the domain name is allowed hots of Django settings file still it's not working.

Any idea whats I am missing

Update:
When I try to create one more sample app and run it port 9000 I am able to access it http://www.equitynotify.com:9000/upcomingresults/ and even if I create it the simple HTTP server 8000 port it is working, only the default 80 port is not working what may be reason

Comment: share your ALLOWED_HOSTS

Comment: @cagrias updated the ALLOWED_HOSTS

Comment: have you restarted nginx after conf change?

Comment: yes sudo systemctl restart nginx used this command

Comment: if i change the server to ec2 domain its working http://ec2-13-233-123-119.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/ but for my domain,http://www.equitynotify.com/admin  its give 404

Answer (score 2):

Django's official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) recommends adding domain names to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` as `www.your_domain.com` if you want to specify full qualified names or `.your_domain.com` in order to cover both `your_domain.com` and `www.your_domain.com`. So you need to add `.equitynotify.com` to your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

EDIT:
You also need to add your django port to the proxy_pass. If you didnt specify any custom port number, django has 8000 as its default port. Here is an example:

```py
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name equitynotify.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not worked, but when I try to create one more sample app and run it port 9000 I am able to access it http://www.equitynotify.com:9000/upcomingresults/ and even if I create it the simple HTTP server 8000 port it is working, only the default 80 port is not working what may be reason

Comment: Maybe you need to add the port in the proxy_pass variable?

Comment: See my updated answer. You can find a more detailed example at https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/use-nginx-reverse-proxy/